# Issue with tweepy installation

Tags: python, twitter

I am facing following error while installing tweepy on Ubuntu.

```
sudo pip install tweepy
Downloading/unpacking tweepy
  Running setup.py egg_info for package tweepy
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
      File "/home/vivek/build/tweepy/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        install_reqs = parse_requirements('requirements.txt', session=uuid.uuid1())
    TypeError: parse_requirements() got an unexpected keyword argument 'session'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

  File "/home/vivek/build/tweepy/setup.py", line 17, in <module>

    install_reqs = parse_requirements('requirements.txt', session=uuid.uuid1())

TypeError: parse_requirements() got an unexpected keyword argument 'session'

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /home/vivek/build/tweepy
Storing complete log in /home/vivek/.pip/pip.log
```

Please help. I googled for this error but could not find any help.

Comment: Traceback is saying it's an error with the tweepy set-up script. Probably a bug on the developer's part... Try downloading the set-up script [directly from GitHub](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy) and running that.

Answer (score 0):

- (1) Please check version of pip.

  ```
  >pip list
  BeautifulSoup (3.2.1)
  oauthlib (1.0.3)
  pip (7.1.2)         # <-- this is mine, today.
  tweepy (3.5.0)
  ....
  ```
- (2) If yours is not so, try this.

  ```
  >pip install --upgrade pip # <-- to upgrade pip by pip
  >pip install tweepy
  ```
- (3.Foot-Note) 
  'cause I use on Windows8, I don't use 'sudo'.
  Please try AT YOUR OWN RISK, Good Luck.